# Correct way to deal with overriding a method and changing the argument type to a subclass

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a class in my framework which I intend to use as the base class for the majority of my other classes, called `Thing`. It has a function `add()` which accepts other `Thing`s:

```
class Thing
{
    public function add(thing:Thing):Thing{ }
}
```

I have several other classes extending `Thing` which make use of `add()`, but I only want to be able to accept relevant subclasses of `Thing`. For example, I have a class `World` in which I want `add()` to only accept instances of `Being`.

In these instances, I obviously cannot do the following, or I get an `Incompatible override` error:

```
public override function add(being:Being):Being{ }
```

Which means I am currently doing something along the lines of:

```
public override function add(being:Thing):Thing
{
    if(being is Being)
    {
        return super.add(being);
    }

    else throw new Error("World only accepts Beings blah blah.");
    return null;
}
```

Which I do not like because:

1. I'm sure that `is` would create a minor performance reduction.
2. It makes the method ambiguous.

I have also considered something like setting the `add()` method to final, making it do nothing and defining a more relevant add method instead:

```
/**
 * Use <code>addBeing()</code> instead.
 */
public final override function add(thing:Thing):Thing
{
    throw new Error('Use World.addBeing() instead.');
    return null;
}

public function addBeing(being:Being):Being
{
    return super.add(being) as Being;
}
```

But this will clutter the class definition.

> Are there any better ways to go about this? Is there a standard way of approaching this problem?

Comment: I think your latter solution would be more in line with other libraries but I'd be pretty skeptical about any real performance hit using `is` in your first solution.  I don't think there is a "better" way then what you've already thought about and both would certainly be acceptable.

Comment: @LDMS I've come up with a third solution which I am experimenting with at the moment: making `add` and `remove` protected, and forcing subclasses to define their own public `addT` and `removeT` methods that call the protected version as well.

Comment: Probably best to use `Interfaces` with that approach.

Comment: @LDMS You wouldn't be able to create an interface which forces you to define a dynamically named pair of methods `add(T)` and `remove(T)` though.

Comment: Yea, If only one class used `addBeing` it would be pointless I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides performance of runtime type checking, I think a real benefit of generics would be compile time type checking.  Template based programming is primitive in Flash, let alone constraint-based type inference and parametric polymorphism.

C# generics implement `where` [constraints on type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), such as:

```
class EmployeeList<T> where T : Employee, IEmployee, System.IComparable<T>, new()
{
    // ...
}
```

A common use case for this is accepting only numerical data types.

Perhaps in C#, a more pragmatic approach would simply be function overloading.

In comparisson, Haxe implements greater support for generics, in which you could probably accomplish rudimentary support for a single base something like:

```
package;

class Thing {
    public function new() { }

    public function add<T>(obj:T):T {
        return obj;
    }
}

class World extends Thing {
    public function new() {
        super();
    }

    override public function add<Being>(obj:Being):Being {
        return obj;
    }
}

class Being {
    public function new() { }
}
```

When compiling to Flash target, most value is lost as classes are transpiled to:

```
public function add(obj:*):* {
    return obj;
}
```

Whether via interface or concrete types, it would be of little value at run time.

Although minimal, `is` operator incurs some overhead - 0.0000095 ms per operation on my 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook.  It took a total of 92 ms to type check 10,000,000 times.  Maybe the greater issue is complexity of so much type checking, and assuredly to your point the class signatures become ambiguous themselves.

Your C-style functional programming approach of `addT()` is probably the highest performance with greatest clarity and portability at the API level.

Sorry, this answer is really of little (no) value; however, this is the most interesting ActionScript question I've seen in some time here - hopefully some comparison to other language constructs inspires or validates your approach.

Comment: Wow I'm really happy to see you post an answer here, always worth reading. This is exactly why I am using MonoGame more and more. If you're interested, I have been working pretty hard even recently on the framework I have mentioned in this question and you can look at [what I ended up with here](https://github.com/MartyWallace/Sentinel/blob/master/src/sentinel/framework/Thing.as). I think I will port this to MonoGame if it turns out OK.

Comment: Cool, it's always an honor to hear from you.  Very interested in your GitHub project, and port to MonoGame, this is awesome.  I like MonoGame and anything Mono in general, and am becoming more interested in OpenTK and Cairo for 2D vector drawing.  Still looking forward to you receiving the first Gold ActionScript tag badge ever.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my solution using interfaces:

```
//Interface for the thing
public interface IThing {
    function add(thing:IThing):IThing;
}

//Interface for the World (can only add beings)
public interface IWorld {
    function addBeing(being:Being):Being;
}

//Being Class
public class Being implements IThing{       
    public function add(thing:IThing):IThing
    {
        return thing;
    }
}

//World Class
public class World implements IThing, IWorld{       
    public function add(thing:IThing):IThing
    {
        return addBeing(thing as Being);
    }

    public function addBeing(being:Being):Being
    {
        return being;
    }
}
```

This final class is used to Test everything. As you can see, If you create a new World instance, and use the add method, it will return null unless the IThing being added is actually of type Being.

```
public function TestClass() {

        var being:Being = new Being();
        var test:IThing = being.add( new Being() );
        trace(test);
        //trace "[object Being]"

        var world:World = new World();
        test = world.addBeing(being);
        trace(test);
        //trace "[object Being]"

        test = world.add(being);
        trace(test);
        //trace "[object Being]"

        test = world.add(new World());
        trace(test);
        //trace "null"
    }
}
```